React context persistence via session storage is inconsistent
I'm trying to achieve data persistence for user authentication on a React context via sessionStorage, but the behavior seems inconsistent at best, and I can't understand where the issue is coming from.
My routing is as follows:
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout chatrooms={chatrooms} />}>
        <Route index element={<ChatHome />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
        <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />}></Route>
        {
            chatrooms.map(chatroom => {
                return <Route key={chatroom} path={`chatrooms/${chatroom}`} element={<Chatroom name={chatroom} />} />
            })
        }
        <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
        </Route>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

All the routes work fine. I login via:
    const [login, setLogin] = useState({username: '', password1: ''});
    const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useContext(LoginStatusContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('loginStatus', loginStatus);
        loginStatus ? navigate('../') : null;
    }, [loginStatus])

    const submit = () => {
        fetch(..., {
            ...)
        }).then(
            (response) => {
                if (response.status === 401) alert("Incorrect username or pin!");
                else if(response.status === 200) {alert("You've been logged in!"); 
                setLoginStatus(true);
            }
        })
    }

And similarly logout via:
    // set storage on successful logout
    useEffect(() => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('loginStatus', loginStatus);
        alert('You have been logged out!');
    }, [loginStatus])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(..., {
            ...
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
            setLoginStatus(false);
        })
    }, []);


The API calls are all fine, and the values return as expected. My main issue is in actually getting things to render properly once the states have been correctly set. For reference, login correctly sets the value of loginStatus to true, and sets the sessionStorage to true as well, and vice versa with the logout script.
The problem arises with this:
    // checks if prior login exists, otherwise sets to false
    let oldLogin = sessionStorage.getItem('loginStatus');
    const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(oldLogin ? oldLogin : false);

    return <Nav className="me-auto">
        <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/">Home</Nav.Link>
            {
                loginStatus ? <Nav.Link as={Link} to="logout">Logout</Nav.Link> :
                    <>
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="login">Login</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="register">Register</Nav.Link></>
             }
             <NavDropdown title="Chatrooms">
                 {props.chatrooms?.map(chatroom => {
                     return <NavDropdown.Item key={chatroom} href={`/chatrooms/${chatroom}`}>
                         {chatroom}
                     </NavDropdown.Item>
                 })}
             </NavDropdown>
         </Nav>

This navbar component(layout) doesn't display as expected– initially after clicking logout, it reflects the state change and correctly hides the logout link, and displays the login/register links. However when I click any other link, it somehow displays the opposite of what is necessary. For instance, if I were to navigate back to one of the chatroom links after logging out, it still shows me as logged in for some reason, and then hides the login & register links. Appreciate any advice as to what might be going wrong here, and can provide any extra code necessary.
